# Does Maven have features like Gradle's 'compile project'?

Tags: maven, gradle, multi-module

I'm using the compile project and compile functions in gradle to decide whether to get dependencies from a remote repository or build locally based on a profile.

```
    if (profile.equals("local")) {
        compile project(":module1")
        compile project(":module2")
    } else {
        compile('me.who.name:module1:1.0.0-SNAPSHOT')
        compile('me.who.name:module2:1.0.0-SNAPSHOT')
    }
```

But, in maven I didn't find a way to do the above.

Does Maven have features like Gradle's 'compile project'?

I don't want to use `<parent/>`

Comment: Technically you could create a profile in your `settings.xml` but in general such differences within a build is in general a bad idea...no matter if Maven or Gradle...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, AFAIK Maven cannot do anything like that.

But maybe, if you elaborate on the problem behind your question, we might find a Maven solution for that.

Comment: I just want to compile the module locally so that debugging is easy in local.
But when deploying it to the server, get the dependencies for the module from the remote repository.

Is there a good way to solve this?

Comment: Why do you need the modules locally for debugging? You can debug into the source code of remote projects without problems.